# pass a parameter from jsp page hook to runtime portlet in same hook

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-theme

I have a jsp page hook, in that I have included a runtime portlet, I need to pass a portlet instance from jsp page hook to to runtime portlet which is in the same jsp page hook.How can I pass the portlet instance id to runtime portlet ? thanks in advance.

I have tried below things: I am getting portlet instance empty

In jsp page hook:

```
<liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="ContentCustomization_WAR_ContentCustomizationportlet" queryString="instance='<%=themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getInstanceId()%>'" />
```

in render() method of ContentCustomizationportlet:

```
String instance = httpRequest.getParameter("instance");
```

in jsp page of ContentCustomizationportlet

```
String instance=renderRequest.getParameter("instance");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jsp page hook:

```
<c:set var="webcontentInstanceId" scope="request" value="<%=themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getInstanceId()%>"/>

<liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="ContentCustomization_WAR_ContentCustomizationportlet" queryString="&instanceId=${webcontentInstanceId}"  />
```

In your jsp retrieve like:

```
String instance=renderRequest.getParameter("instanceId");
```

if you want to get in action class

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest2 = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest);

String instance=httpRequest2.getParameter("instanceId");
```